# CPU undervolting GUI software?

Tags: software-recommendation, lenovo, overclocking

I have Lenovo B580 laptop with core i3. I've followed tutorial to install phc kernel and then phc software to undervolt but this soft is too complicated. Is there any other program whitch is able to change voltages for all cores at the same time?
Or just let me know of any other OC program for Ubuntu.
Thanks!

Comment: have you googled anything? first results: http://www.overclock.net/t/248684/linux-benchmarks

Comment: @geoh this site exists so that people don't have to dig through 52 pages of unmaintained garbage from 2007.